# A .NET 3.5 class library can't read ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings from my new .NET 4.5 application

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, appsettings

A .NET 3.5 class library, which is not mine and already deployed, has a class whose constructor reads an application setting using this method:

```
this.connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyReleasesConnectionString"];
```

I am working on a .NET 4.5 application where I want to instantiate that member class, but the "ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings" array is empty, even after I created a new application setting in my application's "Settings.settings" file. I tried to manually transfer the setting from Properties.Settings.Default.MyReleasesConnectionString (which is the modern way to access application settings) using this:

```
var nameValueCollection = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection(1);
nameValueCollection.Add("MyReleasesConnectionString", Properties.Settings.Default.MyReleasesConnectionString);
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Add(nameValueCollection);
```

But, at runtime, that third line generates an exception telling me that application settings are read-only.

The only options I can come up with at this point are either to use .NET 3.5 for the host application, or to modify the .NET 3.5 class library.

Comment: Gyromite, I tried to re-create, but could not... Please note: you do not want this setting in Settings.settings, you want it in your applications config, like so
<configuration>
  <appSettings >
    <add key="MyReleasesConnectionString" value="yourConstring" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: Thanks, brian chandley, that was the problem!  I thought I'd tried that before, but apparently something was wrong with that test.